# Multiple i.i.d. draws from Normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Say you have $N$ i.i.d. draws of a normal distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. What is the probability that $k$ of those draws are larger than some value $Y$? Is my answer correct?

[image]

Comment: Exactly $k$ or at least $k$?

Comment: Not quite sure actually. Can you answer for both?

Comment: Your answer is correct for "exactly $k$," provided you change $x$ to $y$.

Comment: See [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) for more.

Answer (score 1):

For the exact $k$ draws your answer is correct. Namely, let $X_1,...,X_N$ be i.i.d from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and let $W$ be the number of draws that are larger then $y$, thus $W\sim \operatorname{Bin}(N, p)$, where
$$
p =  P(X > y )  = 1 - \Phi\left( \frac{y - \mu}{\sigma} \right),
$$
hence for exactly $k$ you have
$$
P(W=k) = \binom{N}{k}p^k ( 1 - p)^{n - k},
$$
and for "at least $k$"
$$
P(W \ge k) = \sum_{i=k}^N  \binom{N}{i}p^i ( 1 - p)^{n - i}. 
$$